# Best way to resize top banner images (viewport/html)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, resize

I'm trying to find a better way to resize top banner images, creating different images that fit according the viewport orientation and viewport size without the image be "cutted" or distorced. I created the following code (css + js), and I would like to know if is the proper way, or if exist a better one.

CSS to `<img>` or `<div>` with `background-image`:

```
max-width: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    resizeViewPort();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeViewPort();
});

function resizeViewPort() {
    alert(($(window).height() / $(window).width()).toFixed(2));

    var height = $(window).height(), width = $(window).width();
    var scale = (height / width).toFixed(2);

    if (scale >= 1.7 && scale <= 1.8) {
        if (height <= 736) { // 736x414
            alert("Mobile PORTRAIT");
        }
    }
    else if (scale >= 1.3 && scale <= 1.6) {
        if (height <= 1024) { // 1024x768
            alert("Tablet PORTRAIT");
        }
    }
    else if (scale >= 0.6 && scale <= 0.8) {
        if (height <= 768) { // 768x1024
            alert("Tablet LANDSCAPE or Desktop 4:3");
        } else if (height <= 900) { // 900x1440
            alert("Desktop HD 16:10");
        } else if (height <= 1200) { // 1200x1920
            alert("Desktop FullHD 16:10");
        }
    }
    else if (scale >= 0.5 && scale < 0.6) {
        if (height <= 414) { // 414x736
            alert("Mobile LANDSCAPE");
        } else if (height <= 720) { // 720x1280
            alert("Desktop HD 16:9");
        } else if (height <= 1080) { // 1080x1920
            alert("Desktop FullHD 16:9");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the desired effect?  Maintaining aspect ratio?  Resizing to fixed scales?  It's unclear what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I want to create different images that fit according the viewport orientation and viewport size without the image be "cutted" or distorced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the solution of Saumil Soni, Germano Plebani and http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/, I reach the following solution (thank you all!):

```
/* TOP BANNER */

/* For mobile phones: */
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide414x736.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide736x414.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

/* For tablets: */
@media only screen and (min-width: 533px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide768x1024.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide1024x768.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }    
}

/* For desktop: */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 768px)  {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide1024x768.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (min-height: 720px)  {    
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide1280x720.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (min-height: 900px)  {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide1440x900.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (min-height: 1080px)  {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide1920x1080.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (min-height: 1200px)  {
    .tp-banner {
        background-image: url(../images/style/slider/slide1920x1200.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

With this solution you can upgrade to fits all resolutions you want. (For example, adding 1600x900 image to others desktop devices and 640x320 to new Galaxy Mobiles)

Answer (score 1):

I guess a better way to resize images is through media queries as it is purely a CSS based approach and a HTML recommendation,

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */

    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */

    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
         /* For desktop: */

    }
```

Within the media queries you can specify the dimensions of the banner image that you want for mobile portrait, tablet portrait or full desktop.

**UPDATE:** To detect whether the device is in landscape or portrait mode,

```
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {

 }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {

 }
```

Comment: Nice! But there is a "small" problem. I want to create different images that fit according the viewport orientation and viewport size without the image be "cutted" or distorced.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni the images will not be cutted if you specify the dimensions in  percetage (Eg: 70%) within the above media queries and for the distortion I think their are many online tools that will help you to create images of different width and height without distortion you can use display:none within media queries to display only those images which are suitable for the viewport.

Comment: How can I trace portrait and landscape with media queries? It's possible?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni Yes it is possible, check out my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested in CSS only solution with:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.

Or:

```
background-size: contain;
```

Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area.

Comment: Nice! But there is a "small" problem. I want to create different images that fit according the viewport orientation and viewport size without the image be "cutted" or distorced.

Comment: If you use width: 100%, for example, the height will adapt accordingly without cut.